# Ruby: how to make attribute of User object all lowercase for a search?

Tags: ruby, object, string, attributes, lowercase

I am running a custom search method for my Users model. However it's case sensitive... How do I temporarily change my User object model attributes to be all lower case for my search method?

for example:

if someone searches "Joe", and there are 2 users named Joe, and joe, both should show up.. instead of just Joe

In my User controller

```
def search
  search = params[:search_user].downcase
  @users = User.search(search)
end
```

In my User model:

```
def self.search(search_user)
  if search_user
    #make firstname here!!!!
    find(:all, :conditions => ['firstname LIKE ?', "#{search_user}"] )
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is your database engine? Sqlite3, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle? They have different ways of doing it. For instance, in Postgres it's simply `ilike`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find(:all, :conditions => ['LOWER(firstname) LIKE ?', search_user.downcase])`